# If you close the App Store app while apps are being updated, does it interrupt the updates?

Tags: ios, applications, ios-appstore, software-update

So, while you’re updating apps in the App Store app, you send it to the background, and swipe up and close App Store by accident, while the updates are still commencing and not finished.

Does this interrupt the updates?

Comment: Did you give that a try? What did you observe?

Comment: You need to get out of the habit of swiping up apps to force-quit them [unless they actually hang]. It's very inefficient on battery life.

Answer (score 1):

It does not interrupt the updates.

The App Store app is the frontend used to install apps and updates, but the installation itself is performed in the background and doesn't depend on the App Store app running.

Comment: It’s helpful to add some supporting documentation/resources; it will improve this answer and give more clarity.

Comment: @Ezekiel, I've slightly expanded your answer to provide more detail on why the App Store app doesn't have to be running when updating apps. Feel free to modify my edit or reject it altogether.

Comment: @Allan sometimes there's nothing really to say, there's not really a support document on this type of question. It's just how it works.

Comment: True, but as @jaume has shown with his edit, adding contextual details that can be easily verified goes a long way in providing a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can switch to the Home screen and watch apps continue to download: you will see them greyed out with a progress 'clock' shaded over the icon.

The App Store is a separate process from the installer. But at worst, suspended downloads can be resumed by clicking on the app's icon.

Interestingly, if you disable the App Store completely in Settings, apps that are still downloading will continue to update.